# Type Error with operations with dates (datetime package)

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror, timedelta

I have this code:

```
 import datetime

 last_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 15)
 first_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1)

 date_1 = last_date - first_date

 print(date_1) #this prints: 14 days, 00:00:00

 r=0.05

 fa = 1/(1+r)**(date_1/360)

 fa
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'float' and 'datetime.timedelta'

I'm interested in the number of the days, not with the hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_1` is a `timedelta` object, and as you've seen you can't divide it by a `float`. ]You can extract the number of days from it by using the `days` property:

```py
fa = 1/(1+r)**(date_1.days/360)
# Here --------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

`date_1` is a datetime.timedelta object. You need to get the number of days as an integer.

```
import datetime

 last_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 15)
 first_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1)

 date_1 = last_date - first_date

 print(date_1) #this prints: 14 days, 00:00:00

 r=0.05

 fa = 1/(1+r)**(date_1.days/360)

 fa
```